# How to get landmark using GPS coordinate?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I want to show the user nearest landmarks on the android phone. I can read the GPS coordinates, but don't know how to get landmarks using the GPS coordinates. Is there any easily manageable way? Could someone please put some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this through Google Maps? Is there something in the Google Maps API that lets you get landmarks?

Edit:

Google Maps Places: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

Comment: If I got it right, this solution requires JSON! I need a java/android solution. Any help?

Comment: JSON is just a data format. Java has plenty of libraries to read JSON. Check out [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), probably the most popular.